# Documenting body parameters in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I have a simple APIView to get log files from certain subsystems:

```
class LogParser(APIView):

def get(self, request, subsystem):
    """
    Get logs
    :param subsystem: subsystem name
    :param since: start date
    :param until: end date
    [...]
    """
    since = request.data.get('since')
    until = request.data.get('since')
    [...]
```

It gets `subsystem` parameter as query_param, but takes much more additional data to from JSON to perform additional filtering.

This view doesn't have a representation in models, it does some filesystem operation and returns file so I have no serializer to base on.

I want to document this method similary as in above snippet and make Django Rest Framework with Swagger to understand it and let me to execute queries via swagger with additional parameters.

With get parameters it is working fine, but how to add those `request.data` params to work?

Comment: Try checking https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter.
Even though it says it's for querysets, you still can make your own class, with custom methods. Check https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method